# Android numberPicker to countdownTimer

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, numberpicker

I want to get numPicker's value to countdowntimer
button to start and cancel
but it doesn't work.

```
public class TimeManager extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NumberPicker np1 = null;
    private NumberPicker np2 = null;
    private Button bt1 = null;
    private Button bt2 = null;
    private Button bt3 = null;
    private TextView tv = null;
    private final long t1 = np1.getValue() * 3600*1000;
    private final long t2 = np2.getValue() * 60;
    private CountDownTimer cdt;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_manager);

        np1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numPicker);
        np2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numPicker2);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        np1.setOnValueChangedListener(nplis1);
        np2.setOnValueChangedListener(nplis2);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(btlis1);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(btlis2);
        bt3.setOnClickListener(btlis3);

        np1.setMinValue(0); //設定最小值
        np1.setMaxValue(23); //設定最大值
        np1.setValue(1); //設定現值
        np1.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        np1.setTextSize(60f);

        np2.setMinValue(0); //設定最小值
        np2.setMaxValue(59); //設定最大值
        np2.setValue(1); //設定現值
        np2.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        np2.setTextSize(60f);

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(t1 + t2, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long t3 = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                tv.setEnabled(false);
                tv.setText(t3 + "秒");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                tv.setEnabled(true);
                tv.setText("重新发送");
                cancel();
            }
        };
    }

        NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener nplis1 = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                String value = "" + newVal;
            }
        };

        NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener nplis2 = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                int nowValue = np2.getValue(); //取得現值

            }
        };


        View.OnClickListener btlis1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(TimeManager.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
        };

        View.OnClickListener btlis2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cdt.start();
            }
        };

        View.OnClickListener btlis3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cdt.cancel();
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: @SurajRao it cant let me post my full code

Comment: @SurajRao i try

Comment: @SurajRao i good new here